# move a shelved CL to another workspace for the same user

Tags: perforce, shelve

I have a shelved CL in a workspace which no longer exists ( the admin deleted my entire workspace)
I have set up my workspace again and would like to move the shelved CL to the new workspace; how can I do that. 
I tried the "change ownership" option but it says remove all checked out files from the CL before changing ownership. 
If I remove the checked out files I will loose all the changes; and since I do not have the workspace on which the change was created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the "unshelve" command; that will copy the shelved files from your old workspace's pending changelist into a different pending changelist in your current workspace.

The "change ownership" option SHOULD work under the circumstances you've described, so I suspect something is off, but "unshelve" will work regardless so I recommend just doing that unless you have a specific need to use the same changelist number.

Answer (score 0):

It is true, for "change ownership" to work, the changelist must be empty. But first you shelve the files in the changelist. Shelve has an option to Revert and Remove the files after they are shelved. Then you'll be able to "change ownership"